# Correct way to check if a file exists in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have been using this in my scripts an my coworkers disagree with me.

My script takes in a file as a parameter and creates the file. Then I use the following to see if it was actually created.

`ls -p | grep [filename]`

Then, I see if the file I am trying to create is in the grep list.

but they are suggesting I use

`test -f [filename]`

instead.

What is the proper way to check for if a file exists in Linux?

Comment: If you created the file, you created the file. No point in checking if it "was actually created". It's there.

Comment: More conretely, I suppose you created the file with "touch FILENAME". Just check the return code of that command

Comment: don't parse `ls` , ref [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test -f [filename]` is the way to go. Running both ls **and** grep just for this operation is way overkill.

Comment: Not only an overkill, but also may result in false positives if you filename is part of a (longer) name of existing file.

Comment: Or false negatives if the filename contains a newline.

Answer (score 2):

I know the second method you mentioned is advised in the Linux Foundation's Introductory course. This method will test whether that name exists, and whether it is a file or not. Grep will simply tell you whether it found that string or not.